# Does having a lot of if statements degrade rendering speed of php?

Tags: php, performance

I was wondering if complicated if/else structures in my PHP code could be a bad design decision. Does having a lot of if statements make PHP run slow, site load slower etc?

This is the code:
(I've no idea how wordpress handles is_page etc.)

```
<?php

if (is_page()) {
//
    if (is_page(122)) {
    //subscribe page
    echo "subscribe page";

    }

    elseif (is_page(1263)) {
    //photography course
    echo "photography course page";

    }

    elseif (is_page(array(210,184,128))) {
    //210 copyright policy, 184 privacy policy, 128 contact
    echo "this is either copyright policy, privacy or contact page!";
    //nothing happens here, we don't need social buttons on these pages.
    }

    elseif (is_page(array(379,71,7,45,124,8,105,175,9,125,110))) {
    //379 photo galleries, 71 car photos, 7 conceptual, 45 event photos, 124 fashion, 8 landscape, 105 misc, 175 journalism, 9 portrait, 125 street photography, 110 travel
    echo "gallery pages and albums";

    }

    else {
    //any other page
    echo "any other page";

    }
//
}

elseif (is_single()) {
//
    if (in_category(array(147,196,35))) {
    //147 car photography, 196 car wallpapers, 35 photo stories
    echo "photo posts";

    }
    else {
    //any other post
    echo "any other post";

    }
//
}

elseif (is_archive()) {
//
    //any category
    echo "this is archive template"

}
//
?>
```

Comment: What is "allot"? 10? 100? 10 kajillion? Are you doing a long series of independent ifs? or an if/then/else/else/else chain?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply, I added code to the main post (cause of correct formating). Please check it and tell me what you think! :) thx.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Nope.  In fact, it'll actually speed it up in most cases (because it's allowed to skip over blocks of code).

The only time large numbers of if statements will slow it down is if the condition you're checking requires processing.  An example would be something like:

```
while (true)
{
    if (count($some_array) == 0) { break; }
    /* some other code */
}
```

Ever iteration through the loop checks if `count($some_array) == 0`.  That means that every pass, PHP has to go and manually `count` the number of items in `$some_array` because it may have changed.  This also applies to the stop condition in a for loop.  This is because a for loop can always be rewritten as a while loop:

```
for ([INITIALIZER_ACTION]; [CONDITION]; [POST_ITERATION_ACTION]) { [CODE]; }
```

is the same as...

```
[INITIALIZER_ACTION];
while ([CONDITION]) { [CODE]; [POST_ITERATION_ACTION]; }
```

If you're considering merging a bunch of if statements into one: don't, you won't get any benefits.  PHP does short circuiting which means that if it reaches a point where it *knows* what the outcome will be, it'll skip the rest.

For example, consider `$a = 5; if ($a > 0 || $b > 100 || $c > 200) {}`.
Once PHP sees that the `$a > 0` condition is satisfied, the whole statement resolved to true (because of the usage of OR values) and doesn't bother to check `$b > 100` or `$c > 200`.

So to answer your question: unless you have an ungodly number of conditionals that each require complicated calculations or have side effects, you can usually consider the quantity of them to be inconsequential.
However, as others have noted, having too many if statements can reduce code readability.  In many cases, if you can remove a conditional without it affecting the behavior of the code, then you didn't need it to begin with.

Answer (score 7):

I've just came across an very interesting piece of [article](http://wpshout.com/unconditionally-refactoring-nested-statements-cleaner-code/) from WPShout which uses a very human analogy to invite us to code smarter, and why deeply nested `if { .. }` statements might degrade not only performance but also the code maintainability. If the logic is performance aware, without unnecessary bloated iteration checks, chances are you'll end up with a pretty well organized, responsive-cleaner code.

CODE EXAMPLE (extracted form the article)

> "Let’s make this concrete by looking at two simple code examples:
>   first in bubble-style, then in gateway-style".

**Bad: Bubble-Style**

```
$is_first_thing_working = true;
$is_second_thing_working = true;
$is_third_thing_working = true;
$is_fourth_thing_working = true;

if( $is_first_thing_working === true ) {
    if( $is_second_thing_working === true ) {
        if( $is_third_thing_working === true ) {
            if( $is_fourth_thing_working === true ) {
                return 'Working properly!';
            }
            else {
                return 'Fourth thing broken.';
            }
        }
        else {
            return 'Third thing broken.';
        }
    }
    else {
        return 'Second thing broken.';
    }
}
else {
    return 'First thing broken.';
}
```

**Good: Gateway-Style**

```
$is_first_thing_working = true;
$is_second_thing_working = true;
$is_third_thing_working = true;
$is_fourth_thing_working = true;

if( $is_first_thing_working !== true ) {
    return 'First thing broken.';
}

if( $is_second_thing_working !== true ) {
    return 'Second thing broken.';
}

if( $is_third_thing_working !== true ) {
    return 'Third thing broken.';
}

if( $is_fourth_thing_working !== true ) {
    return 'Fourth thing broken.';
}

return 'Working properly!';
```

**NOTES ON EXAMPLE**

The difference between the two code snippets above boils down to a key distinction:

The bubble method asks if important conditions are true, and only runs code if they are true.

The gateway method asks if important conditions are false, and immediately issues exit instructions for each condition if it’s false.

The bubble method forces nesting, because you have to check **“true, true, true, true”** before you get to the code you want to run. Each **“true”** check is a level of nesting—a condition your code has to live inside.

**The gateway method is not nested:**
as you see, the code is never more than one layer of logic deep. This is because once a given gateway is passed, we can forget about it completely. In other words, since we didn’t exit after our `$is_first_thing_working` check, we automatically know that `$is_first_thing_working` is **true** for the rest of the code.

> "It’s like real life: if you’re sitting next to me in history class, I
>   know you’re a human, a student at my high school, etc.—or else you
>   would’ve never been in my class in the first place. No need to check."

Answer (score 5):

If-clauses are some of the cheapest operations there are, performance-wise.

*However*, what you put *in* the if-clause can be really slow.

For instance, `if (true) { ... }` is going to be extraordinarily fast, but a single `if (calculatePi()) { ... }` is going to take literally forever. The `if` itself is so fast that you'll never have to worry about it, and besides, pretty much everything else you do involves a number of `if`s anyway, for example when you do `for` or `while` loops or `switch` statements. All of those intrinsically contain `if` (one or more) within them.

As for design, a lot of `if`s may be confusing to other developers, depending on what you're writing and how it's written. Sometimes you're better off using switch/case statements or some other application workflow, but to tell you the truth, a bunch of `if`s is probably going to perform faster than any sort of structure you may come up with. But only take that to heart if your *only* concern is performance. Designing software is *not*, I repeat, *not* primarily about performance. Good software design is about other things like maintainability, i.e. how easy it is to read and successfully upgrade your code.

In short, if you're optimizing for performance, don't bother trying to reduce the number of `if`s. Rather focus on what the `if`s are asking about, or what happens depending on whether they return true or false.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 3):

Very complicated if/else structures indicate a bad design in most cases. You can better focus on improving a bad design than optimization, [premature optimization is the root of all evil!](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/80084/is-premature-optimization-really-the-root-of-all-evil).

If you give an example of the type of code you are talking about, it will maybe be possible to give a more detailed answer.

Comment: I am not really familiar with Wordpress, so I do not know what the functions actually do, and what exactly you are trying to achieve with this page. I assume you are creating templates, but maybe you can create start another question for the best approach to do this. As for the if/else statements, you are making if/else/else structures, so that is good, but the performance will be determined by the work done by the Wordpress functions. A lot of database lookups are bad for performance, but simple array lookups should not hinder performance that much.

Comment: ok thx for advice. I'm trying to include social buttons on some pages, and implement them differently for each template file. So if it's post it displays 1 type, if it's page it displays another...

Comment: Ok in such a scenario I don't think these if/else statements are a problem. I assume Wordpress retrieves the page type once from the database, and that the functions you call make use of this retrieved result. But note that this is just speculation on my part.

Answer (score 0):

The question is not about having too many if else statements but 1) the order of them and 2) how efficient your conditions are

1) If else status should be in descending order of probability of the conditions.
In my particular `wp_posts` database table, 80% of the records have `post_status` of "draft", "pending", "trash" etc. but not "publish". About 40% the records have "post" as `post_type`. So, it would make no sense to have

```
if ($post_type=="post"&&$post_status=="publish") {
    doA();
} elseif ($post_type!="post"&&post_status=="publish") {
    doB():
} elseif ($post_type=="post"&&post_status!="publish") {
    doC();
} else {
    doD();
}
```

but it should goes in reverse order

Regarding 2), the database schema of WordPress suggests that `in_category()` will be slow. If it's some query that you write yourself and of course, it depends on how efficient your query is

Answer (score 0):

In a way..**YES**.
I say this considering a Worst case scenario, in this case a very large model object with lots of conditions. Here, the code has to go through all conditional checking which eventually slows down the code. 
Conditional statements pose difficulty for parallelization and vectorization, and a long series of IF-THEN can also cause instruction cache misses and other effects. But if that's what makes the code clearest, then use it.

Answer (score 0):

For python:

```py
def check(string):
  if string == "hi":
    return string
  elif string == "hey":
    return string
  elif string == "hello":
    return string

# on colab  
%timeit check("hi")
%timeit check("hey")
%timeit check("hello")

#output.                   time can vary
>>>130 ns ± 37 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000000 loops each)
>>>146 ns ± 50.1 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000000 loops each)
>>>153 ns ± 39.7 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000000 loops each)
```